# .NET XML Pretty Printer?

Tags: .net, xml

Is there a method in the .NET Framework or a free Open Source library to pretty print XML?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All of .Net's standard XML APIs will format their output.

Using LINQ to XML:

```
string formatted = XDocument.Parse(source).ToString();
```

Or

```
string formatted = XDocument.Load(path).ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the XmlWriterSettings with an XmlWriter

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:\temp\asdf.xml");
var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings 
{
    Indent = true,
    NewLineOnAttributes = true,
};

var writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"c:\temp\asdf_pretty.xml", writerSettings);
doc.Save(writer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XMLBuilder](http://xmlbuilder.codeplex.com) to generate the XML and then call ToString method to get a indented output.