# C++/CLI XMLSerialization Layout

Tags: .net, c++, xml, layout, command-line-interface

Got a problem in C++:

I have written a program which generates an XML file using XMLSerialization (XmlWriter, XmlReader). Now everything is done, excluding the layout. In my generated XML file tabs and the standard XML layout are missing! Is it possible to automatically format this text using a C++ function...?

```
XmlSerializer^ serializer = gcnew XmlSerializer( TESTClass::typeid );

// create an xmltextwriter using a filestream.
Stream^ fs = gcnew FileStream( filename,FileMode::Create );
XmlWriter^ writer = gcnew XmlTextWriter( fs,Encoding::Unicode );

// serialize using the xmltextwriter.
serializer->Serialize( writer, m_testobject );
writer->Close();
```

---

My objective would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root Name="database" Purpose="test" Project="test">
    <!--Test Database-->
    <Description xmlns="x">primarytest</Description>
</root>
```

The code I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><root Name="database" Purpose="test" Project="test"><!--Test Database--><Description xmlns="x">primarytest</Description></root>
```

Comment: "the standard XML layout are missing": what does that mean? Please post the XML you get, and what you expect

Comment: Duplicate of :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063020/net-xml-pretty-printer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the right code in my case:

```
XmlWriterSettings ^settings = gcnew XmlWriterSettings();
settings->Indent = true;
settings->IndentChars = ("    ");
settings->NewLineOnAttributes = false;

writer = XmlWriter::Create( filename, settings );
```