# Automated extraction of word docx archive and pretty print conversion of xml files

Tags: xml, automation, docx, pretty-print, wordprocessingml

If renaming eg. a file **document.docx** to **document.docx.unzipped.zip** it is possiple to extract
that archive eg. to a folder '**document.docx.unzipped**'.
Unfortunatly the extracted **xml-files** are not very readable since all xml-information is in one single line.

I would like to automate the process of extracting a docx archive and converting all **xml-files** from the archive resp. the extraction folder (**document.docx.unzipped**) to **readable/prettyprinted versions** 
(like Notepad++ --> Extensions --> XML Tools --> Pretty Print (XML only with line breaks))

Any ideas for a quick approach?

EDIT1: modified Idea from https://stackoverflow.com/users/1761490/pawel-jasinski

```
#!/bin/sh


# this scripts unpacks and reformat docx files
#
# you need xslt processor (Transform) in your path
# /c/Program Files/Saxonica/SaxonHE9.4N/bin/Transform
#
# make sure to copy remove-rsid.xslt and copy.xslt
if [ "$1" = "-r" ]; then
    remove_rsid=1
    shift
fi

if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
    echo expected name of the word document to be exploded
    exit 1
fi
suffix=${1##*.}
name="$1"

if [ "$suffix" = "xml" ]; then
    suffix=docx
    name=${1/%.xml/.docx}
fi

if [ "$suffix" = "$1" ]; then
    suffix=docx
    name=$1.docx
fi


corename=$(basename "$name" .$suffix)
if [ -z "$corename" ]; then
    echo can not work with empty name
    exit 1
fi

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
DOSDIR=$(cygpath -m $DIR)
FLAT=$PWD/$corename.tmp/flat.$$
FLATOUT=$PWD/$corename.tmp/flat.$$.out


if [ "$remove_rsid" == "1" ]; then
    transform=$DOSDIR/remove-rsid.xslt
else
    transform=$DOSDIR/copy.xslt
fi

# $1 - file name
# 
# formats file as xml
_reformat_xml() {
    echo reformat $1
    #read pause
    xmllint --format $1 -o $1.new
    mv $1.new $1
}

flaten() {
    # xml
    xmls=""
    pwd
    pwd
    #read pause
    for f in $(find . -name '*.xml'); do  
        ff=$(echo ${f#./} | tr '/' '@')
        echo mv $f $FLAT/$ff
        mv $f $FLAT/$ff
        _reformat_xml $FLAT/$ff
        xmls="$xmls $ff"
    done

    # for rels, rename into .xml
    rels=""
    for f in $(find . -name '*.rels'); do  
        ff=$(echo ${f#./} | tr '/' '@')
        rels="$rels $ff"
        mv $f $FLAT/$ff.xml
        _reformat_xml $FLAT/$ff.xml
        #read pause
    done
}

expand_dirs() {
    target_dir=$(pwd)
    cd $FLATOUT

    echo PDW: $PWD
    #read pause

    for f in $rels ; do
        ff=$(echo $f | tr '@' '/')
        mv $f.xml "$target_dir/$ff"
    done

    for f in $xmls ; do
        echo PDW: $PWD
        #read pause
        ff=$(echo $f | tr '@' '/')
        mv $f "$target_dir/$ff"
    done
    cd "$target_dir"
}

echo corename: $corename
read pause
if [ -e "$corename" ]; then
    if [ -e "$corename.bak" ];then
        # echo removing $corename.bak
        rm -rf "$corename.bak"
    fi
    # echo backing up $corename
    mv "$corename" "$corename.bak"
fi 


mkdir "$corename"
cd "$corename"
unzip -q "../$name"

if [ -a $FLAT ]; then
    rm -rf $FLAT
fi
mkdir -p $FLAT

flaten

if [ -a $FLATOUT ]; then
    rm -rf $FLATOUT
fi
mkdir -p $FLATOUT
#exit

#dosflat=$(cygpath -m $FLAT)
#Transform -xsl:$transform -s:$dosflat -o:$dosflat.out
cp -R $FLAT/* $FLATOUT

expand_dirs

read pause #
rm -rf $FLAT $FLATOUT
```

Comment: What is your preferred programming language: C#, Java, something else?

Comment: I first thought to do this with a combination of windows batch and  some commandline tool for the pretty print.
On the other hand I dont like the windows batch "language" very much even though I have collected some experience recently.

Comment: So if there is an elegant way to do this by a "real" programming language, I would prefer C# or pure C/C++.

Comment: Given you mention C#, maybe you use Visual Studio? Are you aware you can drag a docx onto Visual Studio, see a tree of its contents, click on the part of interest, then click the format button to pretty print?  You can edit/save, and Visual Studio automatically re-zips.  Very useful, imho.  Or is your objective something different?

Comment: At least for Visual Studio 2010 I cant see anything interesting happen except that word is started.

My objectives tend to be rather didactical.

One (maybe practical) objective I have in mind is comparing the styles,layout, ... of two different documents manually or with the help of a standard diff tool.
Or you know something like an "advanced docx property reporter" tool?

Comment: Oh you need to install the Package Editor power tool - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/450a00e3-5a7d-4776-be2c-8aa8cec2a75b

Comment: For diff, try Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool

Comment: Thanks for the hints :)
Oh, I found somthing which might also be helpful for the prettyprinting part:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063020/net-xml-pretty-printer

Answer (score 1):

If you ever used `cygwin`, it includes `xmllint` which in turn has the `--format` option. This was my original approach. However `xmllint` did not format attributes the way I liked, so I have developed my own [script](https://gist.github.com/paweljasinski/090273f7fd48867d196e). Since the word documents contain a lot of `rsid` noise, the script has an option to remove it.

I use the following worklflow:

- get a word document, let say `foo.docx`
- `explode-docx -r foo.docx`
- edit `foo.docx` - make a small change
- `explode-docx -r foo.docx`
- `kdiff3 foo foo.bak`

Comment: I actually found a cygwin installation om my pc so I got tempted to try this. (See EDIT 1 in the question of the top of the htread)

Comment: I tried to restore your original approach without xlst processing with the Saxonica package. BTW I had some problems with the odd character used for the tr command wich I replaced with '@'. Well I realized too late that the flattening and expanding was only for xlst processing. Anyhow Thanks :)

Comment: the flattening is only for performance reasons. xslt processor is java based, so it is expensive to call it in a loop. Saxonica has a batch processing mode, but it only works when all files are in the same directory.